# Artifactory yum repository publish with maven-like behaviour

Tags: repository, publish, rpm, artifactory

I can publish an rpm to a yum repo on Artifactory by using generic curl command, but I'm hoping to publish our custom RPMs similar to maven - be able to save daily snapshots with built-in timestamp and resolve dynamic versions from that, etc...

Can anyone please provide guide/resources if this is possible?

If this is not a built-in function, how does one handle daily build of RPMs other than overwriting the previous day's build?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

In cases like that, you can use the timestamp itself as the *release* field of the RPMs, e.g., *name*-*version*-***release***-*arch*.rpm

If builds are infrequent, just the year/month/day (`20151230` is December 30, 2015) works well enough.  If builds are frequent, you could add hours and minutes, e.g., `201512302105` or break it up for readability: `2015.12.30.21.05`.  Keep in mind that `yum` will compare these release values to determine what is the newest release.

Answer (score 0):

I am using for building nightly RPM packages Tito (https://github.com/dgoodwin/tito). When you execute

```
tito build --test --rpm
```

It will generate the release tag using commit SHA similary as suggested by T.Dickey above.